# CCLayer with round corners

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

Is there any way to create the subclass of CCLayer class with rounded corners in cocos2d iPhone library?
Maybe some solutions already exists?
Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I got Original Code Here: [A-roundedrectangle-ccnode-extension](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/a-roundedrectangle-ccnode-extension/) not worked in cocos2d 2.0..So done some updates.

Here is my code for rounded corner layer:

```
int layer_width = 200, layer_height = 100;

CCRoundedRectNode *shareRectNode = [[[CCRoundedRectNode alloc]
                                     initWithRectSize: CGSizeMake(layer_width, layer_height)] autorelease];

shareRectNode.position = ccp(s.width/2-layer_width/2, s.height/2-layer_height/2);
shareRectNode.fillColor = ccc4f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9);
[self addChild: shareRectNode z:3];
```

Download: [CCRoundedRectNode](https://github.com/gururajios/CCRoundedRectNode.git)

Comment: I used your code and besides of some small issues I had to edit, it worked great. Thank you very much for that. But since I'm just starting to get into this stuff, I can't understand, why do I get my rounded layer created with width of 240 look like it has width of 960?